# How to add dynamic prefix to AngularJS routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

What i what is make localized urls like:

- http://example.com/**eng**/somepath
- http://example.com/**ger**/somepath

Let pretend that we always know user lang.

```
angular.module('website', [])
.constant('ROUTES', (function () {
    var lang = 'eng'; // just for example
    return {
        SOME_PATH: '/' + lang  + '/somepath'
  }
})())
.config([..., '$locationProvider', 'ROUTES', function(..., $locationProvider, ROUTES {
    $routeProvider.when(ROUTES.SOME_PATH, {templateUrl: 'pages/some_page.html', controller:     'SomePageController'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
.run(['$rootScope', 'ROUTES', function ($rootScope, ROUTES) {
    $rootScope.ROUTES = ROUTES;
}]);
```

So, if i am add link in html, everithing works:

```
<a href="{{ROUTES.SOME_PATH}}">Some path</a>
```

After i am click a link routing work just as planned.
But if i refresh page or came by direct link ("http://example.com/eng/somepath"), i cannot reach any page and see a 404 page.

Comment: Where is the '#' in your URLs? http://mysite.com/eng/somepath must be http://mysite.com/#/eng/somepath or the browser will be requesting an entirely different URL from the server. Only server settings could remap that back for you.

Comment: @lossleader You don't need the `#` since `$locationProvider` has it's html5Mode set to true

Comment: Yep, it's because $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); In browser without support html5 mode '#' will be exist

Comment: html5 mode isn't magic.. The urls you generate have to come back to the same page or they only work in the current DOM thanks to the history API. Try the docs examples (Books/chapters) and note that going to any of the addressbar urls generated are 404s..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to map the route with the $routeProvider?

```
$routeProvider.when('/:langId/:somepath', 
    {
     controller: 'languageHandlingController'
    })
```

Comment: So, it's work but only in move :langId param to the end of url: http://mysite.com/somepath/ger. May be it cause of '#' in url

Comment: it should work in both ways. maybe is something in your controller. if you want to post more code, i can try to help you.

Comment: Actualy thats no difference for me, so thank you again. Now i'm facing problem with direct links(or external, or refresh) - angular cannot load page by path, but it's look like i should solve it with server settings

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option will be to have a the urls to be something like `http://mysite.com/somepath?lang=en` and then you can just read `lang` directly from the url wherever you need to.

Comment: Yes, it's more traditional path. The only reason is kepp url clear of extra get params. And, imho, urls like http://mysite.com/ger/somepath looks much pretty